# pip install python-novaclient is failing due to netifaces.c

Tags: python-2.7, openstack-nova

I'm trying to install OpenStack python novaclient using pip install python-novaclient
This task fails:  netifaces.c:185:6 #error You need to add code for your platform

I have no idea what code it wants.
Does anyone understand this?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem, and resolved by 

`sudo yum install python-devel python-pip
sudo yum -y install gcc`

Answer (score 2):

Same issue in awx_task container in AWX project (Centos 7), trying to execute

```
pip install python-openstackclient
```

Error was:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-LTchWP/netifaces/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-86uBIZ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-LTchWP/netifaces/
```

Solved with:

```
yum install python-devel python-pip gcc
```

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the order that libraries are imported in the netifaces setup.py and is fixed in version 10.3+ (which you need to install from source). Here's how to install 10.4 (current latest release):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/install/netifaces/
cd /tmp/install/netifaces && wget -O "netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz" "https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/netifaces/netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz#md5=36da76e2cfadd24cc7510c2c0012eb1e"
tar xvzf netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz
cd netifaces-0.10.4 && python setup.py install
```

Comment: I just tried with netifaces-0.10.4.tar.gz from a fresh install of cygwin x86 and it failed with the same error. What is more strange is that it worked from a x64 cygwin with plenty of other packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this question while doing something similar:

```
pip install rackspace-novaclient
```

And this is what my error looked like:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-G5GwYu/netifaces/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-Jugr2a-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-G5GwYu/netifaces
```

After reading the entire output logs, I realized I was missing "gcc" and just needed to install it.

On CentOS 7, my fix was:

```
yum -y install gcc && pip install rackspace-novaclient
```